# Check if sending to webhook URL is successful

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, webhooks

I have this portion of sending data through webhooks in my `models.py`

```
for webhook in webhooks:
   requests.post(webhook.url, json=message):
```

The whole process fails whenever the sending of data is not successful, for some reasons like the given URL is not a valid webhook URL. Is there any way I can avoid the breaking of the process, or check if the sending of data is successful or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your call in a *try-catch* like this :

```
for webhook in webhooks:
    try:
        r = requests.post(webhook.url, json=message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # Do something here
    else:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print('OK')
        else:
            print(f'Not OK : {r.text}')
```